# cannot open recordset in vba

Tags: vba, adodb, recordset

When this vba code tries to open up the recordset, I get the following error:
Run Time Error '3709'
The connection cannot be used to perform this operation.  It is either closed or invalid in this context.

```
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Contact;Trusted_Connection=True;"
objMyConn.Open

strSQL = "Select * from Contact where Lastname like " + Chr(39) + LastSearch + "%" + Chr(39) + " And Firstname like " + Chr(39) + FirstSearch + "%" + Chr(39)

MsgBox strSQL

objMyRecordset.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: What is `cnn` here?  Shouldn't that be `objMyConn` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module; you'll find the VBE screaming at that undeclared `cnn` variable.

Your recordset isn't using any open connection - as the error message is saying.

That said you can very well have single quotes inside the string literals; that `Chr(39)` stuff is just uselessly obfuscating the code.

Also consider using parameters instead. If you're not sure why, read about [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

---

Here's an example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider='SQLOLEDB';Data Source='INSTANCE NAME';Initial Catalog='DATABASE NAME';Integrated Security='SSPI';"
    conn.Open

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT Field1 FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Field3 LIKE '%' + ? + '%'"

    Dim results As ADODB.Recordset
    With New ADODB.Command
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = sql
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Type:=adVarChar, Value:="foo", Size:=255)

        Set results = .Execute

    End With

    Debug.Print results(0).Name, results(0).Value

    results.Close
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Notice it's the `Command` that executes off the `Connection` and *returns* a `Recordset`.

Comment: thanks.  surprised i didn't see that.  i had option explicit but i didn't get variable declaration complaint....

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon can the SQL statement be replaced by running an SQL stored procedure by command type and command text?

Comment: @Jose absolutely! The command text is then just the SP name, and parameters are ordinal (append order matters)

Answer (score 0):

Here's generic ADODB connection set up

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConnection As String

strConnection = "connectionString"
con.Open strConnection
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Tbl", con
```